# Two Sum Problem with HashSet not working with duplicates

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o, hashset

I am working on an assignment where I have to find pairs of numbers summing up to "x" with average/best O(n) or linear runtime complexity. I can not use brute force as it will increase the complexity.

I am using HashSet and using contains method I am checking If I can find (x - array[i]) and printing it. But contains method checks for the whole HashSet where I want to start that search after "i"th position at each iteration. Also, I can not sort them as I have to print them in an order they appear in the input array.

```
          if (hSet.Contains(x - array[i]))
             {
                 Console.Write("(" + array[i] + "," + (x - array[i]) + ")");
                        hSet.Add(array[i]);

                }
             }
```

With Input array { 1, 6, 3, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 9, 1 };

My Output (1,9)(6,4)(3,7)(2,8)(5,5)(5,5)(7,3)(8,2)(4,6)(8,2)(2,8)(5,5)(9,1)(9,1)

Expected output: (1,9), (1,9), (6,4), (3,7), (2,8), (2,8), (5,5), (5,5), (5,5), (8,2), (8,2), (9,1), (9,1)

Comment: A `HashSet` doesn't allow duplicate values to be added to it. It's the point of `HashSet` objects. Why do you expect to see repeated values?

Comment: @John Ok, I missed it, In this case, which c# collection would be appropriate to use?

Comment: To deal with duplicates you could use a hashset of value tuples (`HashSet<(int, int)>`), insert the results in the hashset, and print them at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code work as your expectation with O(n) complexity (in most of case). Using a `Dictionary`, not a `HashSet`.

- First, build the dictionary from array with the key is the item, the value is the count of the item.
- After that, iterate over items, check it with the dictionary and produce the output. Also reduce the count of this item in the Dictionary to avoid unnecessary output later.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        int[] array = { 1, 6, 3, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 9, 1 };
        int x = 10;
        // build dictionary
        Dictionary<int,int> dict = new   Dictionary<int,int>();
        for(int i=0; i< array.Length; i+=1){
            if(dict.ContainsKey(array[i])){
                dict[array[i]] += 1;
            } else {
                dict.Add(array[i], 1);
            }
        }
        // using dictionary
        for(int i=0; i< array.Length; i+=1){
            if(dict.ContainsKey(x - array[i])) {
                int count = dict[x - array[i]];
                if(x - array[i] == array[i]){
                    count -= 1;
                }

                for(int j = 0; j< count; j+=1 ) {
                    Console.Write("(" + array[i] + "," + (x - array[i]) + ")");
                }

                dict[array[i]] -=1;
                if(dict[array[i]] == 0){
                    dict.Remove(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use nested for loop as it will increase time complexity

Comment: The `count` in nested for loop is duplicates number of the item. It will be small in most of cases. So the time complexity is still O(n).
Unless the special cases like `int[] array = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };` and `int x = 2;` the complexity will unable to be O(n)

Comment: @Prasanna, You can generate the large input to check it for performance.

Comment: I am getting very random run times for same input array.

Comment: It means your computer is not in a same sate in every time the code is running. Just check if the running time is acceptable or not.

Comment: I checked on online c# compilers and the give almost constant run times. I think it is a good solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my easy solution using Dictionary. O(n) time.

```cs
namespace TwoSumLeetCode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = { 1, 2, 7, 9, 4 };

            int target = 13;

            Console.WriteLine(TwoSum(arr, target));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // assuming array and target are provided.
        public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length(); ++i)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(target - nums[i]))
                {
                    return new int[] { dict[target - nums[i]], i };
                }

                else
                {
                    dict[nums[i]] = i;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```